# Is there a way to perform a string interpolation in the join clause using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have to translate a query from a legacy database to LINQ but I'm having some problems with it.
Basically I need to do a left join and the property I want to compare is a composite of properties from the second table.

```
SELECT A.DATE, B.UNIT, B.PERSON
FROM TABLE1 A 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.KEY = CONCAT(B.UNIT, B.CONTRACT, B.VARIABLE)
WHERE B.DATE = someDate
```

So far I have tried to create this way, but without success:

```
var date = someDate;

from a in _context.Table1

join b0 in _context.Table2 on a.Key equals $"{b0.Unit}{b0.Contract}{b0.Variable}" into bGroup
from b in bGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
where b.Date == date
                    
select new ResponseDto
{
    Date = a.Date,
    Unit = b.Unit,
    Person = b.Person
})
```

```
{
  "Message": "The LINQ expression '...' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.",
  "ErrorName": "InvalidOperationException"
}
```

When removing the string interpolation the query runs without any problem, so I think the problem is in the way I approached this problem. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried concatenating the values using the `+` operator or `string.Concat` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF cannot translate the `string.Format` call (which is what the interpolated string gets converted into) into SQL because `Format` can do much more than just concatenate strings. It [does support `string.Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions), but only the overload that takes 2 parameters. I would just try string concatenation the old-fashioned way:

```
join b0 in _context.Table2 on a.Key equals (b0.Unit + b0.Contract + b0.Variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Approaches to try depending on your data:

- Concatenate the fields in the C# query like D. Stanly suggested
- Split out the fields in your C# query based on fixed width substrings assuming the concatenated field is fixed width
- If there is not much data in the tables and you are not running this query very often, bring in the raw data an do an in-memory C# query on the data.  This is not recommended unless you know the data searched is very small and the number of queries done per day is small
- Create a SQL view for the query with the fields concatenated and query that instead.  Not recommended if you need to do updates
- If the data is used read-only, add Entity Framework AsNoTracking() to the query
- If one of the data fields, Unit, Contract or Variable, are very selective or unique, then select on that field only in Entity Framework C# query and then filter the results in your C# code.
- Entity Framework pass-through SQL

The general idea is to reduce the subset of data brought back into C# memory to as small as possible and then do filtering in C#.

Note: If this is millions of rows in the tables, you'd need a different approach.  Most likely a SQL approach.